# Logging - How to use the same logger as a class for different files?

Tags: python, class, logging

How can I use the same logger as a `class` for different files?

Example:

#### `mylog.py`

```
import logging

class MyLog():
    def __init__(self):
       pass
    def getLogger():
       logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
       logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
       ch = logging.StreamHandler()
       ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
       formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
       ch.setFormatter(formatter)
       logger.addHandler(ch)
       logger.addHandler(file)
    
    #etc list of formatting that I want to be the same for all the files using this class
```

How can I call the same logger for this file?  (I'm guessing I need to pass the file name rather than using name__)

#### `myfile.py`

```
import mylog

logger = mylog.MyLog() #? how can I get correctly the logger from the other file? 

logger.info("Test Message") #I want this logger info to use the formatting specified in mylog.py

'''
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you are showing here. Maybe the `__init__` from MyLog is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module can contains member variables in addition to definitions. So you could do (more or less):

#### `mylog.py`

```
import logging

def getLogger():
   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   ch = logging.StreamHandler()
   ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
   ch.setFormatter(formatter)
   logger.addHandler(ch)
   logger.addHandler(file)

#etc list of formatting that I want to be the same for all the files using this class
   return logger

logger = getlogger()
```

#### `myfile.py`

```
from mylog import logger

logger.info("Test Message") #I want this logger info to use the formatting specified in mylog.py
```